# How to increment count in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to increment the quantity count in my database everytime I click my button.

This is my angular directive:

```
var count = 0
  $scope.postNote = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    var token = $scope.userInfo.$$state.value.accessToken
    $scope.userInfo.$$state.value.cart.quantity.push(count += 1)
    $http.put('/api/me/cart?access_token=' + token, $scope.userInfo.$$state.value)
      .then(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result)
      }, function (err) {
        deferred.reject(err)
      })
    return deferred.promise
  }
```

This is my api:

```
router.put('/me/cart', wagner.invoke((User) => {
    return (req, res) => {
      try {
        var cart = req.body.cart
      } catch (e) {
        return res.status(status.BAD_REQUEST)
                  .json({ error: 'Sorry, you have failed in life' })
      }
      req.user.data.cart = cart
      req.user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .json({ error: err.toString() })
        }
        return res.json(user)
      })
    }
  }))
```

Finally, this is how my document look:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56ca4dc77aaab42f074250ba"),
    "password" : "$2a$10$KnIVYcIjE/AYfUnMgkWhc.bQ1Luxo8XRUq/lnuPXKsOKR8YEz2m7O",
    "username" : "ken",
    "data" : {
        "cart" : {
            "quantity" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
            ]
        }
    },
    "__v" : 0
```

I just want the quantity element to increment everytime I click it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I made the change in my directive.

```
var count = 0
$scope.postNote = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    var token = $scope.userInfo.$$state.value.accessToken
    $scope.userInfo.$$state.value.cart.quantity = count++
    $http.put('/api/me/cart?access_token=' + token, $scope.userInfo.$$state.value)
      .then(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result)
      }, function (err) {
        deferred.reject(err)
      })
    return deferred.promise
  }
```